# linking pages in different html files in same directory in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have two `.html` files in my jQuery Mobile app directory `(myapp/html/...)` .In `main.html` i have a page which i declared as:

```
<!--Home page-->
<div data-role="page" id="home" >
...
</div>
```

and in the second `.html` file which is just a login page, i have a button which i want to wire to the `home` page in `main.html.`

I have tried:

```
<link href="html/main.html"/>
```

and then:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="html/main.html/home">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
```

but i get an error message saying `"error loading page"`. I have also tried adding `#` just before `home` in the link but then the error message doesn't even show.

I know that in "normal" html, if the two html files are in the same folder, all i have to do is

```
<a href="thefile.html">my link</a>
```

But since one html file has several pages embedded in it in jQuery Mobile, how do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to solve this problem you need to understand how jQuery Mobile page handling works, and you can't solve this problem.

When jQuery Mobile handles pages only first **HTML** files is fully loaded into the **DOM**, all intermediate files are loaded only partially. When I say partially I mean **HEAD** will be stripped away and only FIRST **data-role="page"** will be loaded.

So if you have 2 pages, for example lets say first one is called **main.html** and second one is called **second.html**, and lats say both of them hava 5 **data-role="page"** div containers.

All pages inside **main.html** will be loaded into the DOM during app initialization, but when you you change page to **second.html** only first **data-role="page"** div container will be loaded into the **DOM**, everything else is going to be discarded.

Read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/multipage-template-vs-multi-html-template-in-jquery-mobile/)**.

Comment: Thanks Gajotres, kinda sucks to know there isn't a way around this.

Comment: Welcome to jQuery Mobile ;) unfortunately this information, among many others, is unavailable in official documentation :(